# After upgrading .Net core 2.2 to 3.1 facing issues with Azure WebJobs and other azure libraries

Tags: azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-webjobs

We are upgrading the .net core version for one of the application from .net core 2.2 to 3.1, we are facing issues with azure libraries. In this application we are using Azure web jobs and azure functions. Please help me with this? I'm attaching libraries for the reference.

we have two applications.

1. Azure function application **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions** with latest version one and it is not showing any library with yellow mark

[image]

2. coming to second application which is simple class library with azure libraries, after migrating .netcore 2.2 to 3.1 , the libraries getting yellow mark as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue and faced the same errors in namespaces when migrated from .Net Core 2.2 to 3.1 in Azure Functions and resolved it by following steps:

1. Created Azure Functions Project with Version 2.2 and below is the following output when running the function:
   [image]
2. After changing the ***TargetFramework*** and ***AzureFunctionsVersion*** values to ***netcoreapp3.1*** and ***v3***, found errors in the namespaces of the function classes like below:
   [image]
3. In the terminal of VS Code Project, run this command which installs the required function sdk when using ***.Net Core 3.1*** with Azure Functions ***v3***

`dotnet add package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions --version 3.0.3`

[image]

Then, Run the function as you can see below output:

[image]

#### Updated Answer

Added the .Net Standard 2.1 Class Library Project to the existing Azure Functions Project and the class library project is included with these nuget packages installed:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Worker 2.20
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 4.0.1
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 5.0.0
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage 4.0.4
Microsoft.Extensions.Azure 1.1.1
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 6.0.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 6.0.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah 4.0.8
Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish 2.0.0
```

[image]
Migrated the Class Library Project Library from .Net Standard 2.1 to netcoreapp3.1 and tried to build the project, it failed.
After Adding this code the class library .csproj file,

```
<ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

and this nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore` latest version to the project using nuget package manager,
then the solution is built successfully as you can see the below output:

[image]

Comment: there are two applications, 1. azure function application and it is not showing any yellow mark against the azure libraries
2. class library with azure libraries but it is showing yellow marks against the azure libraries.  I have updated the query, please check and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service does not support .NET Core 3.1 out of the box in all regions. Therefore, if you want to use .NET Core 3.1, you need to enable the .NET Core 3.1 SDK extension.

You can also check this [map](https://aspnetcoreon.azurewebsites.net/#.NET%20Core%20SDK) to see the available areas running .NET Core 3.1 (Windows only):

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/04/16/Announcing-.NET-Core-3.1-LTS-Generally-Available-on-App-Service.html

Or you need to use Web App from Docker to create your application:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/